# tensorflow does not install correctly

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda

I have installed tensorflow on Windows 10, and a check gives the following results:

First, I checked my Anaconda install with:

```
(base) H:\>anaconda-clean --yes
Backup directory: C:\Users\cbrau\.anaconda_backup\2021-07-05T115344

(base) H:\>conda update --all
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
(base) H:\>
```

OK. So far so good.  Now I checked the installation of tensorflow:

```
(base) H:\>pip install tensorflow
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (2.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy~=1.19.2 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.19.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six~=1.15.0 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: flatbuffers~=1.12.0 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.12)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-preprocessing~=1.1.2 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.9.2 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: gast==0.4.0 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt~=1.12.1 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: google-pasta~=0.2 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-nightly~=2.5.0.dev in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (2.5.0.dev2021032900)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py~=0.10 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-estimator<2.6.0,>=2.5.0rc0 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (2.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel~=0.35 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.36.2)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor~=1.1.0 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard~=2.5 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (2.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio~=1.34.0 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.34.1)
Requirement already satisfied: astunparse~=1.6.3 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: opt-einsum~=3.3.0 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py~=3.1.0 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions~=3.7.4 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.7.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard~=2.5->tensorflow) (3.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3,>=2.21.0 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard~=2.5->tensorflow) (2.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=41.0.0 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard~=2.5->tensorflow) (52.0.0.post20210125)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard~=2.5->tensorflow) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.15 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard~=2.5->tensorflow) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard-data-server<0.7.0,>=0.6.0 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard~=2.5->tensorflow) (0.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth<2,>=1.6.3 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard~=2.5->tensorflow) (1.32.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard-plugin-wit>=1.6.0 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard~=2.5->tensorflow) (1.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa<5,>=3.1.4 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard~=2.5->tensorflow) (4.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard~=2.5->tensorflow) (4.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard~=2.5->tensorflow) (0.2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard~=2.5->tensorflow) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1->google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard~=2.5->tensorflow) (0.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard~=2.5->tensorflow) (2021.5.30)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard~=2.5->tensorflow) (1.26.6)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5,>=3.0.2 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard~=2.5->tensorflow) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard~=2.5->tensorflow) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=3.0.0 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard~=2.5->tensorflow) (3.1.1)

(base) H:\>
```

No complaints, so I then tried to use tensorflow:

```
(base) H:\>python
Python 3.8.10 (default, May 19 2021, 13:12:57) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py:30: UserWarning: loaded more than 1 DLL from .libs:
C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.PYQHXLVVQ7VESDPUVUADXEVJOBGHJPAY.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.WCDJNK7YVMPZQ2ME2ZZHJJRJ3JIKNDB7.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
  warnings.warn("loaded more than 1 DLL from .libs:"
2021-07-05 11:55:04.225189: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import keras
  File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import models
  File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\models.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import functional
  File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py", line 32, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import training as training_lib
  File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 51, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.saving import save
  File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\save.py", line 30, in <module>
    import h5py
  File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import version
  File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\version.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import h5 as _h5
  File "h5py\h5.pyx", line 41, in init h5py.h5
AttributeError: type object 'h5py.h5.H5PYConfig' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'
>>>
```

I don't understand why I'm getting these errors.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Charles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This normally indicates some installation problem, possibly not installyng h5py headers. What worked for me was `pip uninstall h5py` then installing h5 through conda with `conda install -c anaconda h5py`.